# como colocar um operador relacional C++?

Tags: c++, divisão

O exercicio eh para Ler o valor de uma compra nas Lojas Sua Melhor Compra e mostrar o valor das prestações de acordo com a quantidade de parcelas desejada pelo usuário. A loja está vendendo seus produtos a vista ou parcelado em até 10 vezes sem juros.

n estou conseguindo limitar a quantidade de parcelas em 10x

por enquanto esta assim o codigo...

```
    #include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {

float valordacompra;
int quantidadedeparcelas;

cin >> valordacompra >> quantidadedeparcelas;



cout << ("Valor da Compra:") << valordacompra << endl;
cout << ("Quantidade de parcelas:") << quantidadedeparcelas << endl;

float valordecadaparcela;
valordecadaparcela= valordacompra/quantidadedeparcelas;
cout << ("Valor de cada parcela:") << valordecadaparcela << endl;
```

Comment: Pode ser algo do tipo (após a leitura): `while (quantidadedeparcelas < 0 || quantidadedeparcelas > 10) { cout << "Quantidade de parcelas inválida. Reinforme" << endl; cin << quantidadedeparcelas;}`

Comment: preciso só da um return 0 no final, mas valeu ajudou mt